# How to calculate the output of this neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks

What is the output value of the network for these inputs respectively, and why?
(Linear activation function is fine.)

[2, 3][-1, 2][1, 0][3, 4]

My main question is how you take the 'backwards' directed paths into account.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The neural Network in the image is a "[Recurrent Neural Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network)"(RNN). Because of the connection leading backward from `h10` to `h01`, `h10` has to be a "memory node" (mn), meaning it can store its value from the previous input. The basic functionality of an RNN can be seen in this animation:

---

[image: animation]

---

#### Your example:

In the beginning, the storage of the mn is initialized with a value, probably 0.
Now the first input is fed into network:

- `i0` = 2
- `i1` = 3
- `h00` = (`i0` * 0.4) = 0.8
- `h01` = (`i1` * -0.9) + ("the stored value of `h10`" * 1.2) = -2.7
  ("the stored value of `h10`" in the first run is 0.)
- `h10` = (`h00` * 0.85) + (`h01` * -0.2) = 1.22
- `out` = (`h10` * 0.3) + (`h01` * 0.1) =  0.096

Now you can feed the next input through the network and use -2.7 as "the stored value of `h10`" and so on. You can also add an activation function as you would for any other NN.

Comment: Why is `out` calculated later than `h10`? Technically, `out` and `h10` is on the same layer, just like `h00` is to `h01`. What is the algorithm for the calculation order?